# input character in string, after 2nd character

Tags: php, string

I am pulling values from a database that contain military time as 1330 (don't ask why)

I want to convert the 1330 to 13:30 and then run strtotime to turn 13:30:00 into 1:30pm

I am having writers block as to how I can place a colon : between the 2 and 3 character, in 1330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using:

```
$time = substr($time, 0, 2) . ':' . substr($time, 2);
```

But Why are you splitting .You can directly get your output 1:30pm with:

```
echo date("h:i a",strtotime(1330));
```

The second option will give you result more faster. Why wasting time splitting.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5):

One obvious way is to use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr):

```
$time = "1330";
$new_time = substr($time, 0, 2) . ':' . substr($time, 2);
```

Another solution is [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$time = "1330";
$new_time = preg_replace('/(\d{2})(\d{2})/', '\1:\2', $time);
```

Also, [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split) is possible:

```
$time = "1330";
$new_time = implode(':', str_split($time, 2));
```

Answer (score 3):

The lazy way:

```
chunk_split('1330', 2, ':') . '00';
```

Comment: Nice! First time I see `chunk_split`. Very useful in this scenario +1

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to just do:

```
$time = '1330';
$part_a = substr($time, 0, 2);
$part_b = substr($time, 2, 2);

$new_time = $part_a . ':' . $part_b;
```